# TPU custom chip available with Google Cloud ML

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-tpu

Which type of Hardware is used as part of Google Cloud ML when using TensorFlow? Only CPU or Tensor Processing Unit (custom cards) are also available?

cf this [article](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/05/Google-supercharges-machine-learning-tasks-with-custom-chip.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud TPUs are available to the public as of 2018-06-27:  https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/release-notes

This was announced at Google Next '18:

https://www.blog.google/products/google-cloud/empowering-businesses-and-developers-to-do-more-with-ai/

Answer (score 2):

Cloud ML currently focuses on CPUs. GPUs and TPUs will be available in the future.

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to see something more beefy for compute

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing (December 2017), GPUs are available, see https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/training-overview

If you use the `gcloud` command line utility, you can e.g. add the `--scale-tier BASIC_GPU` option when submitting jobs to mlengine. This currently gives runs your tensorflow code on a Tesla K80.

There is also a `CUSTOM` scale tier which allows more complex configurations and gives access to P100 GPUs (see https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/using-gpus ).

The TPU service is in 'alpha' status according to https://cloud.google.com/tpu/ and one needs to sign up to learn more.