# tensor processing unit in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-ml

Google offers Machine Learning Units for it's cloud machine learning platform, are these the Tensor Processing Units which gained so much attention a while back?

I have requested this information from Google, but the sales department did not have technical information available.

This question was answered over a year ago here: [TPU custom chip available with Google Cloud ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40051506/tpu-custom-chip-available-with-google-cloud-ml)
but as cloud is moving at amazing speed I am requesting up to date information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ML units are used as a until of billing on [Cloud Machine Learning Engine](https://cloud.google.com/products/machine-learning/), similar to vCPU*hours on GCE. They simpy track your usage of the product per hour.

[Cloud TPU](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/) is an IaaS offering for using the TPUs you mentioned on Google Cloud.